# Apply different CSS based on Angular material stepper orientation

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I have an angular material stepper that can be displayed vertically or horizontally based on user input. Is there a way to apply a different CSS style to the stepper based on the orientation?

For example, apply red background to the stepper's content when vertical and blue background when horizontal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an [ngClass] or [ngStyle] based on the same condition that you use to display the stepper in vertical/horizontal.

e.g If your current code is something like

```
<mat-stepper orientation="verticalStepper ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal'">...</mat-stepper>
```

Add an ngClass attribute binding

```
<mat-stepper orientation="verticalStepper ? 'vertical' : 'horizontal'" [ngClass]="{ 'vertical-stepper': verticalStepper, 'horizontal-stepper': !verticalStepper }">...</mat-stepper>
```